# Find a DOM object's node Name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to construct a JSON out of the form elements in an HTML page.

Being new with Javascript, I did some digging around and found that `nodeName` property can be used to get the HTML tag name of a DOM node. I tried to compile code to print the tag name using alerts, and this is what I managed to come up with, but I am unable to get it to work:

What am I doing wrong?

```js
    $(function() {
      $('#submit').click(function() {
        var button = $(this);
        var frm = button.parentNode; // or button.parent();
        alert(button.nodeName); // should print INPUT
        alert(frm.nodeName); //should print FORM
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` not `$(this)`, `$(this)` is jQuery object not dom object

**Update :** To get dom object from jQuery object you can use `$(this)[0]` or `$(this).get(0)`. Visit https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

```js
$(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var btn = this;
        var frm = btn.parentNode;        
        alert(btn.nodeName);    
        alert(frm.nodeName);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The question is asking for a `jQuery` solution. This answer removes jQuery altogether from the solution. It is correct, but not what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

it's  `btn.get(0).nodeName`

```
 $('#submit').click(function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var frm = button.parentNode; // or button.parent();
    alert(button.get(0).nodeName); // should print INPUT
    alert(frm.get(0).nodeName); //should print FORM
});
```

Comment: What exactly does get(0) return?

Comment: return the html element , not the jquery object

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that you are using jQuery, your `btn` object is not a don node, but it is a jQuery object. Thus, you have to use jQuery methods, such as `.prop()`. In this case, `.prop("tagName")`.

Working example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var frm = btn.parent();

    alert(btn.prop("tagName"));
    alert(frm.prop("tagName"));

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input id="submit" type="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Note that for jQuery versions lower than 1.6, you have to replace `prop()` with `attr()`.

Sources:

- [jQuery API: prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop) (Note the list of properties right after the beginning of the page.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please direct me to the documentation for this?

Comment: I have added a link to the source at the end of my answer, not you have a list of properties/attributes in that page. Here's the link again: http://api.jquery.com/prop/